# Switching to Ubuntu - advice needed

Tags: system-installation, windows-7

I have had Windows 7 which got stuck in a loop due to an upgrade error. I can only start windows in safe mode at this point. I have worked with Microsoft tech support and they have not been able to resolve the issue.  It does not seem to be a hardware issue and since I have lost my Windows 7 disc, I was thinking it'd be a good time to switch to Ubuntu.

Has anyone done this in a similar situation before? Will there be any issues or things I should anticipate with the install?

Comment: You're basically asking about doing a clean install of Ubuntu, right? Whatever problems windows has are irrelevant as long as your hardware works. So currently it doesn't sound like there's a question here...  just try Ubuntu with a live USB/DVD, if you like it install it, then if there's problems post a Q about it, if you can't find an answer through searching here

Comment: This is not a question - rather asking for advice on whether you should install Ubuntu (offtopic) Make a choice. Do you want to try and fix the problems on Windows or try out Ubuntu? (rhetorical question).

Answer (score 1):

The big question is how much RAM do you have. You'll want to have at least a gigabyte and you're way better off with four... but one gig will do.

Go to http://ubuntu.com and download the latest version. If you have a CD drive burn the image to CD. When you boot from the CD, select "Try ubuntu without installing". This should get you to a desktop where you'll be able to check out the basic functionality and whether things like sound etc are working... though if it's a Win 7 machine I expect everything on it will be well supported.

If you don't have a CD drive you'll want to take the ISO and use it to create a bootable USB thumb drive. You can find instructions for how to do that on a windows system at https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

If you're thinking you're going to completely ditch Win7, then try clicking on "Install Ubuntu" and go through the install process. As its your first time, I'd suggest going "erase disk and install ubuntu" and let the installer figure out the partitioning for you. After you install fire it up and take a look around.

If you have a list of what's in your PC that will be helpful (video card, sound card, RAM, cpu, etc) as far as people being able to help you out with any particularities (esp. wrt video... depending on what's in there you may find that you'll be able to wring a LOT more performance out by installing specific drivers that aren't included with the default install).

There will be a steep learning curve at first. You'll want to do some reading about how unix type systems work (for example, no drive letters... instead one mounts partitions at various places in the file system). On the plus side, as you learn about how linux works you'll find you end up with a far greater control over your computer than you can get with Windows. The best part is that after you go linux you'll never get held up for money to make sure your computer works ever again... you may have to read and figure stuff out but you'll always be the one in control.

Personally I highly recommend taking a shot at it. I went linux about a decade back and I don't regret it in the least.

Oh, and it's a golden era for games under linux; if you have a steam account install the client and see what you've got available. Currently my big games are CS:GO, The Long Dark (so beautiful), and Overload (Descent spiritual descendant by the original developers of Descent Back In The Day... most excellent). There are many many great games available under linux now so you'll want to browse around in steam to see what you can get.

Good luck!

Comment: Ubuntu (16.04) only needs 512MB of ram, it says... but if windows can run with the ram then a linux can probably run better. FYI I think Canonical or Red Hat will take your money and give you linux support if you really want to spend money, otherwise you're on your own searching & solving your own problems (worth it though, as long as it's relatively quick ;-)

Comment: Note that "erase disk and install Ubuntu" will erase the whole Windows partition, including any documents, videos, etc. that are stored on it. (In *some* cases they can be recovered, partially, usually with considerable effort.) This is obvious to many of us but it's not obvious to people who are just starting out. Even if the OP does not plan to use the Windows system ever again, they should make sure they have offloaded their documents and important files from it before erasing the Windows partition.

Comment: Eliah: Yep, true that. I should have pointed that out. MKlein: when you boot up the ubuntu install media and select "try ubuntu without installing", you can open up the file manager and see the existing windows volumes in the panel on the left. If you click one of them it should mount the volume and make the files visible on the right pane. You can then choose to select files and copy them somewhere so that you don't lose your data.